# Bash: Insert variable content into command substitution as arguments - how to quote correctly?

Tags: bash, command-substitution, variable-substitution

I really really don't find a solution to this problem:
Say I have a variable that has multiple lines, each line should be one argument in the end.

```
line   1
line two
...
```

I only get this data at runtime, but it should be build like this to an command:

```
answer="$(dialog --menu 'Menu title' 0 0 0 'line   1' - 'line two' - ... 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)"
```

(Data has to be separated by an - but this is not a problem.)

I think I really tried every possible combination, but it won't work out. I checked this site already but I >think< it is not offering a solution to my problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Should I try to switch word splitting of?

This is my code as of now:

```
list=""
while read p; do
    list="$list '$p' - "
done <<< $line_separated_input

answer="$(dialog --menu 'Chosse sth' 0 0 0 $list 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)"
```

Using an array also didn't work (As suggested here in (5): https://superuser.com/a/360986) :( How to stop word-splitting inside of quoted stuff, even if this quoted stuff is inserted because of variable substitution?

Edit: Thanks everybody, quoting `$line_separated_input` was part of the solution. Using it together with an array list instead of a variable finally solved my problem.
You can check for yourself, having an additional command substitution makes things harder:

```
> list="'a  a'   'b    c'"; echo "$(echo $list)"
'a a' 'b c'
> list="'a  a'   'b    c'"; echo "$(echo "$list")"
'a  a'   'b    c'
```

Both have not the intended output. This is only achieved if I do the following:

```
> list=('a  a'   'b    c'); echo "$(echo "${list[@]}")"
a  a b    c
```

Tadaa! Thanks everybody :)

Comment: Would `tr '\n' '-' <<<"$line_separated_input"` work for you?

Comment: Just use quotes!!! `... done <<< "$line_separated_input"` ***with the quotes!!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `gniourf_gniourf` commented, you probably just need to double quote your variable  like `... done <<< "$line_separated_input"`. An argument enclosed in double quotes presents itself as a single word, even if it contains whitespace separators, thus it prevents `word splitting`, which can lead to unintended consequences.

To better exemplify, see the following examples:

```
var="/tmp/my directory"
mkdir -p "$var"
```

**Output**: the directory `/tmp/my directory` is created

Now, without double quoting:

```
var="/tmp/my directory"
mkdir -p $var
```

**Output**: the directory `/tmp/my` is created

Comment: This was not the full solution, see my edit. But thanks! :-)